# Why is the question about e-mail spoofing closed?

Tags: discussion

[How to Stop Email Spoofing [closed]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73402/how-to-stop-email-spoofing) is an interesting question, even when its formulated as a careless one-liner. But the question is valid, the asker did basic research (he mentions SPF) and the accepted answer is a good start as well.

The question could attract quite a few more high quality answers, especially when someone would edit the question a bit to make people more aware of why this is an interesting question.

I think this should not have been closed.

Answer (score 5):

It was closed in 2014 and was too broad.

In 2019, it has become a bit of a canonical answer for all those basically asking the same thing.

"How do I prevent email spoofing?" needs more definition and more research because there are lots of ways to prevent spoofing and there are different kinds of spoofing. There are too many ways to answer the question. If SPF/DKIM/DMARC do not meet the requirements, then the problem needs more definition and the resulting question would be much more on-topic.

Comment: Ah okay. I just saw it without looking at the date. I think it could use some work and then make a good candidate for a canonical question. Closing it discourages people from doing the neccessary work.

Comment: agreed - I'm hoping the accepted answerer adds in DMARC, else we can do it for him